# Python3 How do I make randomized multiple choice questions/answers?

Tags: python-3.x

Basically I'm doing a multiple choice question president quiz on who served before the others in said multiple choice question. I've gotten it down fully looped with out the randomness but now I've incorporated arrays and random questions, basically I need to figure out how to make multiple choice questions and then define the logic so that when a person inputs 1,2, or 3 the game will look at all three listed options and know which one is the lowest on the presidents list to identify the correct answer.

````
lives = True
import array
import random

print("Welcome to Ahmed's U.S Presidential Quiz!")
print("Please enter your name!")
userName = input()

def answer():
if response == presidents

def lifeCount():

    if livesRemaining == 0:
        print("You're out of lives! Good luck trying again!")
        quit()
    
    if livesRemaining == 0:
            quit()

while lives:

    presidents = ["George Washington","John Adams","Thomas Jefferson","James Maddison","James Monroe","John Quincy Adams",
    "Andrew Jackson","Martin Van Buren","William Henry Harrison","James K. Polk","Zachary Taylor","Franklin Pierce","James Buchanan","Abraham Lincoln",
    "Ulysses S. Grant","Rutherford B. Hayes","James A. Garfield ","Grover Cleveland","Herbert Hoover","Calvin Coolidge","Franklin D. Roosevelt","Harry S. Truman",
    "Dwight D. Eisenhower","John F. Kennedy","Richard Nixon","Jimmy Carter","Ronald Reagan","Bill Clinton","George W. Bush","Lyndon B. Johnson"]
    
    
    
    livesRemaining = 3
    
    
    print("Nice to meet you", userName,)
    print("Today you'll be taking a quiz on which U.S President served first out of three options!")
    print("You'll have only three chances to mess up! Let's get started!")
    print("Choose either number 1 2 or 3 on your keyboard!")
    print(random.choice(presidents)); print(random.choice(presidents)); print(random.choice(presidents)) 
    
    
    response = input() 
    
    if response == "1":
        print("Correct! 1/10!")  
    else:
        livesRemaining -= 1
        print("Incorrect!")
        lifeCount() ```
````

Comment: choose 3 random numbers that are not the same, look at `random.sample`

Comment: the function `def answer():` seems incorrect. indentation.